# Transform creating wavy text in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, text, transform

Folks, I have text on a div that has transform: rotate(3deg). In Firefox, the text is rendered wavy. Removing the transform to the div fixes the waviness. Is there a way for me to have my cake and eat it too?

HTML:

```
<div class="card turn-right">
    <div class="card-text">
         <p>Blah. Blah. Blah.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
    display: block;
    width: 550px;
    height: 375px;
}
.turn-right {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
            transform: rotate(3deg);
}
```

**Edit:**

Additional information: I have to use a @font-face for this project.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605194/improve-css3-text-rotation-quality

Comment: @MattGibson Saw that, tried it, doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: I don't think your problem can be fixed yet, sadly, at least not in Firefox. Looks like there are simply outstanding bugs with the font rendering. [This page](http://www.panic.com/~cabel/firefox-bug.html) shows the same problem, referenced in [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=534064) raised in 2009...

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding perspective

```
.turn-right {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(9999px) rotate(3deg);
            transform: perspective(9999px) rotate(3deg);
}
```

No need for -moz-transform in modern browsers

By the way, the same bug is present in webkit browsers.

Why does this work ?

I don't have a real answer, because I don't have the source for the browser. But my guess is the following. The browsers have a very good rendering engine, that can do lots of things, and does it pretty well. But doing all this is most of the time expensive (read: **makes the browser slow**). So, most of the time it is trying to guess: is this really necessary ? Do I really need to calculate the xxxx  of the yyyy in the zzzz to display this ?

And some of the bugs come from that guess being incorrect, and omiting a necesary calculus.

The solution then, is to put there something that makes the browser rendering engine think "wait, I really need to calculate that, that is not the easy case".

Also in this line are fixes like *translate3d(0,0,0)*   or *translateZ(0)* or *backface-visibility hidden* . What is the sense in translating something 0px ? They force the browser to do something the complicated way instead of the easy way, and solve - optimize the result.

Comment: This appears to make the issue much better. Maybe it's just my eyes, but I feel like there's still a bit of waviness, but it's very legible and almost perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is still a bit of waviness. The only way that I know to make it appear better is to increase the angle.  rotate(6deg) looks better than rotate(3deg).

Comment: The client was happy enough with it, so that makes me happy enough with it. Out of curiosity, why did that work? It doesn't seem like an obvious solution to me.

Comment: Added some explanation .. Glad that it helped you !