# Firefox Mac OSX - CSS transformed text does not skew smoothly

Tags: macos, css, firefox, transform, skew

While implementing some fancy CSS3 and making it work on all browsers, I'm now lost on Firefox for Mac:
The text skews, but it's not looking very nicely. Hard to explain, it looks like it can't use subpixels and therefore always jumps by full pixels, making the text looking odd.

I've created a jsFiddle, so you can test around:

http://jsfiddle.net/8cYgM/2/

Note:
The example looks fine in the following browsers: Chrome, Firefox (Windows 7), Safari (Mac), Internet Explorer 11

```
<div class="skewthis">
    <p>Some text download start</p>
    <p>000000ooooo</p>
</div>
<p>Note: Text looks not as smoothly skewed in Firefox on Mac as in other browsers</p>
```

CSS

```
.skewthis {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    width:350px;

    transform-origin:0% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin:0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0% 0%;

    transform:skew(0deg,2deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
    -ms-transform:skew(0deg,2deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform:skew(0deg,2deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);

    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.skewthis p {
    font-size:17px;
    line-height:28px;
    padding:0 15px;
    display:inline-block;

    background-color:#009ccc;
    color:#fff;
    margin:12px 0 0;
}

.skewthis p:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer your looking for might be found here :

[Improve css3 text rotation quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605194/improve-css3-text-rotation-quality)

It looks as though this is a common issue within FireFox's browser.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried those out before, looks like there's no fix for Firefox then.
The odd thing is that it looks perfectly fine on a Windows 7 Firefox, I didn't expect Mac Firefox to be this much worse.